# What are some best practices for designing mobile friendly websites?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, design-patterns

I have a large amount of experience with general programming languages such as Java, Python and C. I self-study frequently and I am familiar with Design-patterns from the Gang of Four. I have recently been making mobile friendly websites, however overviewing my solutions I can surely suggest that my frontend development skills are not very good, despite a *solution* being found. I would suggest that I do not implement best practices and I would like to find a palce where I can improve my ability to create *mobile response websites*. I read a lot of the bootstrap4 framework and it helps for things like navbars, however certain things are not possible.

For example, a recent mobile responsive component of my website can be described in this image[image: https://imgur.com/a/6SgaOVY]

The general problem I solved was creating a full-width square with an image, text and an arrow.

For the desktop. The button has a width of 30% and the img is on the left.
For mobile, the button has width of 100%, the img is on top, below is the text and finally is the button etc...

To solve such problem I used react and completed is roughly this way

```
let result;

if (desktop){
     result = /* 40 lines of html to create the solution for desktop */ 
} elif (mobile) {
     result = /* Same 40 lines of html, button width change, html reordering 
     to move the image on top */
} else {
     result = ...
}

{result}
```

As you can tell I am essentially tripling the code for each case sent back to the user. So far my only understanding of mobile responsive websites is to add a lot of series css conditionals using @media queries.

I have industry level experience with general programming languages but so far most of my frontend development is self-taught.

I would like to find any source of information that teaches best practices for creating efficient, readable, well-written css/html/js that is using to create mobile friendly websites.

Feel free to comment on my previous code example for recommendations

Comment: You can read about bootstrap on following link - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @Sethuraman I read a lot of the bootstrap4 documentation, but how can it help in situations where I want items rearranged such as my situation above?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge with website development, but one solution for some of your UI rendering problem will be:

Use of Viewport Meta Tag:
The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.
The viewport meta tag tells browsers to fit the width of your page to the screen of the device type the visitor is coming from.

You should include the following  viewport element in all your web pages:

Comment: View port is to view website in mobile browser as seen in desktop site , but we cannot view the website as responsive, we need to write media queries to make it responsive or we can go with library like bootstrap link -- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions #1: Different Stylessheets for different media types**
If you're not a friend of media queries in css you can create different stylesheets for different media types.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 400px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 401px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

**Suggestion #2: Set classes with javascript**
Still not a friend of media queries in css? You can also assign a class like "mobile" to the html or body tag according to the viewport or useragent.
While listening to an event, you can change that class dynamically.
But you will have the issues of media query usage, too...

*I'm not a firend of this solution, its more or less the same as media queries!*

**Suggestions #3: Using preprocessors**
Even if yo"re not a friend of media queries, give it a try!
I personal hate media queries becuase the handling feels very strange. But using a preprocessor like LESS or SCSS fixes many issues css has.
You still has to use conditional media queries, but less redundance and they are easier to maintain.

**Suggestion #4: Webserver configuration**
You can configure your webserver to serve different websites depending on the user agent. But the deployment of a new version could be harder...

**Conclusion**
I would suggest using suggestion #3.
For me its the most intuitive way to assign media queries and I think it will best fit to your usecase.
It will also improves your stylesheets.

Irrespective of your problem i would suggest that you use a preprocessor.
Even if you choose a framework like Bootstrap. Most of them provides a api for one or more preprocessors for a better integration.